# how to test this method using mockito or Junit?

Tags: java, unit-testing, methods, mockito

@Override
        public void storeInfoInStaging(StagingInfo stagingInfo) throws BusinessException {

```
        INotificaDao iNotificaDao = NotificaDaoFactory.getInstance().getNotificaDao();
        try {
            iNotificaDao.storeInfoInStaging(stagingInfo);
        } catch (DataException e) {
            LOGGER.error(e.getMessage(), e);
            throw new BusinessException(NotificaConstants.DB_ERROR_CODE, NotificaConstants.DB_ERROR_MESSAGE);
        }

    }
```

Comment: first you decide what you want to test, then you write the test, then you run it. if it's strictly about 'how to use Mockito', that depends on what you want to do with it, there are enough Mockito tutorials/documentation around to help starting with that

Comment: This method is pure boiler-plate. I'd just test the implementation of `INotificaDao` instead and call it a day.

Comment: Better you take care of such methods in Integration Test

Comment: If you did want to test it, you should inject `iNotificaDao` instead of looking it up from the global factory. Failing that, you'd have to instrument that global factory to return your mock implementation.

Comment: Thank u Stultuske,Thilo ,Yati Sawhney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know your className, you need to replace your className your own className. Maybe, you can do something like that just check for the method really invoke method.

```
  @Mock
  private INotificationDao iNotificationDao;
  private ClassName className;

  @Before
  public void init() {
    className = spy(new ClassName());
  }

  @Test
  public void storeInfoInStagingGivenStaginInfoValid() {
    Mockito.doNothing().when(className).storeInfoStaging(stagingInfo);
    className.storeInfoStaging(storeInfo);
    Mockito.verify(iNotificaDao, atLeastOnce()).storeInfoStaging(staginInfo);
  }
```

Comment: you're welcome, please could you accept my answer ? @charlierawool